# Set resource annotated field of a class in unit tests

Tags: spring

I have a class.

```
public class Definitions{
@Resource(name="schemas")
private Collection<String> schemas;
}
```

This class is initialized via spring.
Spring file:test.xml

```
<util:list id="schemas">
    <value>"A"</value>
    <value>"b"</value>
</util:list



<bean id="Definitions" />
```

Is there some way I can insert value to private field schemas(annotated with Resource) in my unit test without using spring. I tried using setting private variable via Reflection but that also did not help(probably due to security restrictions).

Even using spring,
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("test.xml");
It is not able to load schemas in Definitions bean. I get "NullPointerException" while accessing schemas.

Answer (score 1):

Add a setter for it:

```
public class Definitions{
    private Collection<String> schemas;

    @Resource(name="schemas")
    public void setSchemas(Collection<String> schemas) {
        this.schemas = schemas;
    }
}
```

This is the principle of dependency injection: you inject dependencies manually, vis constructor or setter injection, in your unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the following:

Insert the list in you spring.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">
    <util:list id="listTest">
        <value>Valor 1</value>
        <value>Valor 2</value>
    </util:list>
</beans>
```

Reference the list in your code:

```
@Resource(name = "listTest")
private List<String> listTest;
```

I've tested here and it works fine on Spring 4 and 3, there's no need to implement a setter method.